# Updating a WsdlRequest value via SoapUI Pro

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to update a WsdlRequest parameter values at runtime using groovy.
Say I have a WsdlRequest that contains two parameters: name, address.  I’d like to pass to this WsdlRequest the values I would like the request to have prior to creating a WsdlSubmit instance.  I know the base code is this:

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject()
WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, wsdl, true)[0]
WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) iface.getOperationAt(3)
WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest(requestName)
request.setRequestContent (requestContent);
```

The requestContent is the soapxml in a String format. Is there a good way to insert my values (say I want name value to be ‘Test’ and address value to be ‘Example’ for the request)?  I’d rather not store the xml as a string and update this if I already have that information when I generate the request.

Here is an example of the xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:data="http://test.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <data:updateFieldName>
         <fieldId>?</fieldId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <newFieldId>?</newFieldId>
      </data:updateFieldName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Prior to creating the WsdlRequest, I have created a groovy object that contains the values I want to fill into the above soap xml message.  Let's say this object states the fieldId = 10 and the newFieldRequest = 15.  I a not sure how to pass those values into the request.  Is there a way to do this with the SoapUI API?  I do have a pro license also.

Comment: Do you want to add specific values in some of the xml nodes? Can you share your xml and explain in what nodes do you want this values?

Comment: Yes I can absolutely do that.  let me update my question now.  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `XMLHolder` to parse your xml, and the you can use `setNodeValue(xpath, value)` to specify the value for this node, in your case this looks like:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

// your request content
def requestContent = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:data="http://test.com">'+
   '<soapenv:Header/>'+
   '<soapenv:Body>'+
      '<data:updateFieldName>'+
         '<fieldId>?</fieldId>'+
         '<newFieldId>?</newFieldId>'+
      '</data:updateFieldName>'+
   '</soapenv:Body>'+
'</soapenv:Envelope>'

// parse it as xml bean
def requestXml = new XmlHolder(requestContent)
// set your node values
requestXml.setNodeValue("//*:fieldId","10");
requestXml.setNodeValue("//*:newFieldId","15");
```

Then to get the xml content as `string` again you can use `getXml()` method as follows:

```
WsdlRequest request = ...
// to set in your request use getXml()
request.setRequestContent (requestXml.getXml());
```

For more info you can take a look at [XMLHolder api documentation](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html)

There is also another way to do this without groovy script; using properties. You can add a properties in for example your `TestCase` and then use it directly in your `TestStep` request like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:data="http://test.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <data:updateFieldName>
         <fieldId>${#TestCase#yourProperty}</fieldId>
         <newFieldId>${#TestCase#anotherProperty}</newFieldId>
      </data:updateFieldName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you're interested in this take a look at: [Working with properties](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html) and [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html)

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

I write a whole example with your code and xml holder using a public `wsdl` due you can try and get the result without the NPE and compare with yours to check what is going on:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

wsdl = "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL"
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject() 
WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, wsdl, true )[0] 
WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) iface.getOperationByName( "GetGeoIP" ) 
WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest("Request") 
def defaultRequest = operation.createRequest(true) 
def xmlHolder = new XmlHolder(defaultRequest)
xmlHolder.setNodeValue("//*:IPAddress","127.0.0.1");
request.setRequestContent (xmlHolder.getXml());
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: thank you very much.  I will give these a try.  I agree that I should move towards using a TestSuite/TestCase/TestStep mentality and this is so a PoC.  Much of the SoapUI documentation appears to be for GUI users which is important but not where I want to head this project. I didn't think to use a TestCase Property for a TestStep either. thanks for the input! I see the GroovyUtils API and I thought I would need to use that to get at the TestStep.

Comment: am I able to use def requestContent = operation.createRequest(true) to get the value to pass into request.setRequestContent(requestContent)? I am getting a NullPointer.  I will accept the answer I am trying to get it to work but I know you are correct :)

Comment: I also attempted to hardcode the string as you did and I still get the nullpointer... trying to determine what I did incorrectly

Comment: I think that the NPE is thrown because your `WsdlRequest request` is probably null.

Comment: when i create the defaultRequest as below it isn't null. but when I create a XmlHolder instance using the default request I get the NPE... I am just not sure
{WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, wsdl, true )[0];
        WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) iface.getOperationByName( "getOrdersForContract" );
        WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest( "Request" );
        def defaultRequest = operation.createRequest(true)
        def xmlHolder = new XmlHolder(defaultRequest)}

Comment: I make a try with the whole code and I'll say you something.

Comment: I write a whole example with public `wsdl` and works well without throwing any NPE, try with it and compare with yours. Hope this helps `:)`.

Comment: I will give this a try a little later today.  I really do appreciate the comments!

Comment: I have a working example so thank you again for all your help!

Comment: yes it does.  and it plugs in very well with my test framework :) also no need for the pro license as there is no need for dataprovider.  always a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the groovy script for the following:

1. Update all WSDL Definitions in the project.
2. Recreate all requests to updated ones.
3. Takes backup of old requests.

---

```
 import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateRequests
    import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateTestRequests

    project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project; //get the project reference
    def ifaceList = project.getInterfaceList(); //get all the interfaces present in the project in a list

    //start a loop for number of interfaces
    for(int i = 0; i < project.getInterfaceCount() ; i++)
    {

    def iface = project.getInterfaceAt(i);
    def url = iface.definition;
    iface.updateDefinition( url, true); //updateDefinition(String url , Boolean createRequests)

    //The above part updates the definition
    //The part below recreates the requests based on updated wsdl definition

    //syntax - 
    //recreateRequests( WsdlInterface iface, boolean buildOptional, boolean createBackups, boolean keepExisting, boolean keepHeaders )

    recreateRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
    recreateTestRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
    }
    //End of Script//
```